# How to perform % in MIPS without using div operator

Tags: assembly, mips

I need to perform C language i -= (j%64) using MIPS, but I am not able to use DIV. How can I find the remainder in MIPS without using DIV. (i variable is stored in $t0 and j is stored in $t1)

Comment: `int den = 0; while (j > 64) { ++den; j -= 64; } i -= j;`

Comment: Ask a C compiler, see if it uses a slow `div` instruction at all.  https://godbolt.org/

Answer (score 4):

Speaking of math (and without regard to a computer system) if we wanted some number modulo 100, we would simply take its last two decimal digits.

We can do the same in binary, with powers of 2 instead of powers of 10 like we grew up with.

Let's observe that 64 is a power of 2 (the 6th in fact).

Thus, modulo 64 is the lowest 6 binary digits (bits) of the input.

Try the `ANDI` instruction to move only the lowest 6 bits to another register.